# TypeError in console on Chat FAQ page

Tags: bug, chat

In any site's Chat FAQ page, there is a console error when clicking on any link in the sidebar. For example you can check the [Meta SE Chat FAQ](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/faq)

The error message is:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.curCSS is not a function

the error occurred in the help.js file.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Uncaught TypeError]

Comment: I can repro in Chrome 66.0.3359.117 on Windows 10. From my testing it also appears that the error happens ~100 times per second.

Comment: also reported on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399075/chat-stackoverflow-com-faq-broken-collapse-expand-functionality