# How to view/copy source of a message in chat?

Tags: support, chat

When I see a message in chat and I want to know how it was written, what do I do?

This might be useful for example if I do not know how some other user achieved some special formatting in chat. (For example, not everybody knows how to strike through the text in chat. Formatting for hyperlinks in chat - and in comments - is different from what is generated in post if you enter link through the editor. And there are certainly many other situations when something like this might be useful.

Comment: From some things that people asked in chat, it seems that some users are unaware of this - so I thought that it might be useful to have this documented somewhere. (Maybe I am not good enough in searching - but I did not find an older question about this.)

Comment: A more direct way to work out how to do something is the help link on chat, which tells you the basics of formatting.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's true - still there are some things which are not [described in the chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq). And also links to a specific section of the FAQ [do not work as expected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304225/collapse-show-more-does-not-work-in-chat-faq-when-linked-to-a-specific-section). (What I want to say - sometimes looking at the source is the fastest option.)

Answer (score 6):

When you go to any message in the chat transcript, you can click on the small arrow on the left next to the message. Among other things the choices you can do there are "permalink" and "history". (If you are in a chat room, you do not have possibility to choose "history" - but you can still choose "permalink" which brings you to the transcript.)

[image: screenshot]

After clicking on "history" you can see all revisions of that message. (There is only one revision, if the message was not edited.)

For example, if you go [to this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50038602#50038602) after clicking on history [you get what was actually entered](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/50038602/history). For a message which was edited the history [shows all revisions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/50038721/history). (And for such messages, the "history" link is available even if you access the menu directly from the chatroom - not only from the transcript.)